# Copy file,create duplicates in different directory with predefined list of filenames

Tags: shell, shell-script, files

I have a file `rock.mpg`  in the folder directory `/folder1/folder2`. I need to create multiple (340) duplicate copies of this file in a different directory say `/folder1/folder2/folder3` but with different unique filenames.

The unique names for the 340 duplicate copies are random and also not sequential. They are already defined in a separate text file file `abc.txt` which I have.

A sample of duplicate file names in `abc.txt` as follows

```
MS123.mpg
DW235.mpg
WQ6748.mpg
HDJ74.mpg
...
...
```

so on

Can this be achieved with shell script?

Comment: Yes.  Worth revising the question to show some existing file list, how you'd expect new list to look, and some of the abc.txt file content.

Comment: You really want copies? Or can your problem be solved with links?

Comment: Thanks @Bernhard .  Yes, I really want to make copies. Basically something which copies the file 'rock.mpg' to new location and then renames it one by one as per the list of filenames defined in abc.txt

Comment: Do you need each copy in a different directory? i.e. ./folder3/MS123.mpg, ./folder4/DW235.mpg, etc? Or ALL 340 copies in folder3?

Answer (score 1):

Should be rather easy with `xargs`:

```
xargs -a abc.txt -i cp /folder1/folder2/rock.mpg /folder1/folder2/folder3/{}
```

- `-a abc.txt` tells `xargs` to read from `abc.txt` (instead of from standard input as usual)
- `-i` tells `xargs` to replace `{}` with a line of input

Test it with:

```
xargs -a abc.txt -i echo cp /folder1/folder2/rock.mpg /folder1/folder2/folder3/{}
```

Answer (score 0):

with BASH only:

```
while read newname ; do
    cp old/dir/rock.mpg /new/dir/"$newname"
done < abc.txt
```

or even in a single line:

```
while read newname ; do ; cp old/dir/rock.mpg /new/dir/"$newname" ; done < abc.txt
```

The mechanism is to read each line of abc.txt as the varaible newdir and then copy the old file to the new location with this new name.